# Jupyter notebook cells doesn't stretch to fit multiple plots

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am using matplotlib charts and ipywidgets to display plots in the ipynb. However When plotting multiple plots, the cells do not stretch to fit all the plots. Instead a scrollbar on the side shows. How can one enable the plots to stretch and fit on the cells?

```
with output:        
    clear_output()
    plot_a()
    plot_a()
    plot_a()

def plot_a():
    plt.bar(x, y)    
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript magic for the help:

```py
%%javascript
IPython.OutputArea.auto_scroll_threshold = 9999;
```

Tested with and works:

```py
i = 0
while i < 100:
    print('test')
    i +=1
```

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

i = 0
while i < 10:
    plt.plot([1,2])
    plt.show()
    i +=1
```